# using sonata_type_collection against a custom form type instead of a property/relationship with another entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

is it possible to use `sonata_type_collection` against a custom form type instead of a property/relationship with another entity?

Something like this:

```
$formMapper->add('foo', 'sonata_type_collection',
    array('type' => new \myVendor\myBundleBundle\Form\Type\BlockType() 
));
```

Which throws me the following error

```
The current field `contingut` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ``
```

**EDIT:**

Something like this did the trick:

```
$formMapper->add('contingut', 'collection', array(                                 
    'type' => new \myVendor\myBundleBundle\Form\Type\Block1Type(),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'by_reference' => false 
));
```

Comment: No one has ever used Model based forms in conjunction with Sonata? I mean, does everybody ever used SOnata, only, for Entity based forms? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Instead of using a custom form type so far I override the form_admin_fields.html template and then catch the collection name e.g. foo and include a _foo.html.twig template which is based on the edit_orm_one_to_many.html.twig for example when using OneToMany. I then define the form and template as needed in twig. But using a custom type sounds very interesting! Did it work out for you, @user846226 ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a custom type in your example, you can also use a native entity type.

```
$formMapper->add('cars',
                            'collection',
                            array(
                                'type' => 'entity',
                                'allow_add' => true,
                                'allow_delete' => true,
                                'by_reference' => false,
                                'label' => false,
                                'options' => array(
                                    'class' => 'YourBundle:Car',
                                    'property' => 'name',
                                    'label' => false
                                )
                            )
                        )
```