# How to add two sonata_type_collection fields of the same property in the same admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Suppose you have `ArticleAdmin` and `CommentsAdmin`. It is easy to add one-to-many editing in Sonata:

```
$formMapper->add('comments', 'sonata_type_collection',
    array(
        'by_reference' => false,
    ),
    array(
        'edit'   => 'inline',
        'inline' => 'table',
    )
);
```

However, suppose I have more complicated `CommentsAdmin` form and it can has two visualizations depending on the kind of comment in it. I would like to display two sonata_type_collection fields in `ArticleAdmin` for grouping different types of comments into two different edit tables.

Adding another `add('comments', ...)` is of course incorrect, and adding `add('comments2', ...)` results in exception.

I will manage separating comments between two fields in admin, but how to create `sonata_type_collection` field on a virtual entity field `Article::comments2`? How to tell Sonata Admin what kind of collection should it be?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you but:

```
->add('categoryHasMedia', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'label'             => 'Logo\'s'
            ), array(
                'edit'              => 'inline',
                'inline'            => 'table',
                'link_parameters'   => array('context' => $context),
                'admin_code'        => 'appstrakt.project.admin.category_has_media',
            ))
```

By using admin_code you can tell which admin class you want to use for that sonata_type_collection if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Good idea to override admin, but this gives exception exactly like in this answered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932028/using-sonata-type-collection-against-a-custom-form-type-instead-of-a-property-re. After looking in source code, I think I will have to set that fake ORM relationship manually.